# Clarification in a proof of that the closure of a set is closed?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Robert Ash's book on real analysis. There is this theorem (item b):

> [image]

And this is the proof:

> [image]

When he concludes that we can have a ball around $x_n$ and we can select $z\in B_s(x_n)$. We know this $z$ exists because we are assuming that $x_n$ is a limit point $(x_n\in E')$, isn't it?

Comment: By definition, the closure of a set $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain $A$. From there it is trivial to see that closure is an idempotent operator.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes but that isn't what I am asking (I guess). I liked your proof tho.

Comment: @BillyRubina Yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes.  $x_n$ is a limit point of $E$. so $B_s(x_n)$ must cointain a point $z \ne x_n$ where $z \in E$.

Comment: It is just a pet peeve of mine to define topological concepts such as "closure" in terms of sequences in metric spaces when the concept itself is more broadly defined - in particular, in spaces in which limits of sequences need not be unique.

Comment: Of course the issue isn't that $z$ is in $B_s(x_n)$.  It's that $z\in E$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a proof by contradiction is easier than a direct proof.

Let $x_n\in\bar{E}$ and $x_n\to x$. We want to show that either $x\in E$ or $x$ is a limit point of $E$.

Suppose $x\notin E$. We want to show that, for every $r>0$, $B_r(x)\cap E\ne\emptyset$.

Fix $r>0$. By definition of convergence, there exists $n$ with $x_n\in B_r(x)$. Since $x_n\in\bar{E}$, we have either that $x_n\in E$ or $x_n$ is a limit point of $E$. In the former case we're done. Otherwise, there exists $0<s<r$ such that $B_s(x_n)\subseteq B_r(x)$. Since $x_n$ is a limit point of $E$, $B_s(x_n)\cap E\ne\emptyset$. Therefore $B_r(x)\cap E\ne\emptyset$.